# Fastest way to create a square nxn matrix from 1d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Suppose the following numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # can be any array
```

I want to know the fastest way to generate the following operation:

```
n = arr.shape[0]
result = np.tile(arr, (n, 1)) - arr.reshape((-1, 1))
print(result):

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

(1) How to efficiently create matrix "result" (because n >> 0 can be very large) ?

(2) Does this matrix have a particular name ?

Comment: *"Does this matrix have a particular name?"* A matrix where the diagonals are constants is a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).  I don't know if the special case that you are creating has a special name.

Comment: See [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html).

Comment: @Warren Weckesser That looks like a different operation...

Comment: @isedgar Is your input array always the numbers 1 to n like that, or is that just a misleading example? If it is always like that, I'd expect the input to be just the number n instead...

Comment: @Kelly Bundy no, this is a toy example.

Comment: Could you make your example clearer then, for example change the 3 to 30? As you can see from the non-equivalent answers, it's not entirely clear what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit faster:

```
result = arr-arr[:,None]
```

cursory benchmarks, nothing scientific. (timeit 100 times with arr):

```
          5 items (arr) 100 times   10,000 items (np.arange) once
OP:       0.0006383560000000066     0.7902513520000001
This one: 0.0001735200000000381     0.3640661519999999
Kelly's:  0.00027326299999996806    0.36036748900000015 (see comments)
```

Comment: How about `np.subtract.outer(-arr, -arr)`? (I'm on a phone, writing a benchmark is inconvenient, plus I assume you already have one.)

Comment: @Kelly, it's 50% slower than mine but still more than twice as fast as the OP's

Comment: Thanks. What n did you test?

Comment: @Kelly, I only tested with arr,  with np.arange(10000) yours is 1% faster

Comment: Ok thanks. Given that they ask "because n >> 0 can be very large", I think that larger case is more relevant. But good to know both.

Comment: @ Kelly, Indeed, your solution gets ahead progressively with the magnitude of n (3% faster at n=20K,  I'm not patient enough to wait for higher values but there is clearly a trend :)

Comment: Testing on small arrays is largely pointless. The time is going to get overwhelmed by the overhead.